# obfuscate third part libs inside aar file

Tags: android, obfuscation, aar

We have an Android project that we want to distribute as an .aar file (a commercial sdk). 
We have dependency on a third part paid library, a jar file, that is inside the libs folder of our Android Library Project. 
When we assemble the aar, we are able to open it, and we can see that it has a folder libs, with this third part dependency jar, the same as we have imported.

I want to know how can we obfuscate this lib so other people cannot just grab it from our aar and use. I saw a plugin called shadow for gradle https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow, but it seems it only works for jars.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you care? If it's a third party library. Presumably it's available elsewhere

Comment: It is not a free library, we pay to use it, we cannot just give to other people

Comment: Just to update this question with what we did. We ended up using proguard, standard Android tool for that. In our case this third party library had some dependencies with native code, so I had trouble to obfuscate some parts of it because the link between java and the native could would break, and the error was useless. At the end, we obfuscate only the main lib entry points, so other people would not be able to initialize and use them directly.